# well-ordering principle for natural numbers from the definition of real numbers.

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-number-theory, real-numbers, well-orders

Define the set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ by means of the following axiom: There exists a totally ordered field $(\mathbb{R},+,\cdot,\leq)$ which is Dedekind complete. We also assume that $a\leq b$ implies $a+c\leq b+c$ for all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\leq b$, $0\leq c$ implies $ac\leq bc$ for all $a,b,c\in \mathbb{R}$.

We derive the well-ordering principle for $\mathbb{N}$. Namely, we claim that every non-empty subset $S$ of $\mathbb{N}$ has a minimum.

We prove this fact as follows:

Since $\mathbb{N}$ is bounded below, the completeness of $\mathbb{R}$ provides us with $\alpha:=\inf S$. It suffices to show that $\alpha\in S$.

Arguing by contradiction, suppose that $\alpha\notin S$. Then $\alpha+1/2$ is not a lower bound; that is, we can find $m\in S$ so that $\alpha<m<\alpha+1/2$. Again, since $m$ is not a lower bound, one can find $m^\prime\in S$ such that $\alpha<m^\prime<m<\alpha+1/2$. This means that $m-m^\prime<\frac{1}{2}$. But this is impossible, as the difference of every pair of different natural numbers cannot be lower that one.

My question is: how can one derive from the definition of real numbers, the fact: for all $m,m^\prime\in\mathbb{N}$, $m>m^\prime$ one has $m-m^\prime\geq 1$? I would do by induction, however, as far as I know, the well-ordering principle is equivalent to the induction principle, so it would be tricky to use induction to derive the well-ordering principle. Should one to include the induction principle as an axiom?

Comment: How do you define $\Bbb N$ in this context?

Comment: As $1\in\mathbb{R}$ by the axiom of field, I would define it as the set of finite sums of $1$. But I am not sure if this definition is right as I need the notion of 'finite' which comes from the definition of natural numbers.

Comment: Or maybe I can define natural numbers as the intersection of all inductive subsets of $\mathbb{R}$; that is, all the sets $S$ that contain $1$ and satisfies $x\in S$ implies $x+1\in S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we define $\Bbb N$ as the  intersection of all inductive subsets ($=$ contains $1$ and closed under "$+1$"), then we immediately get the induction principle: If $\Phi$ is a predicate with $\Phi(1)$ and $\forall x\colon\Phi(x)\to \Phi(x+1)$, then the set $\{\,x\in\Bbb R\mid \Phi(x)\,\}$ is inductive and hence $\supseteq\Bbb N$.
Hence you are free to use induction to show the desired result.
For example, we might show

> $\Phi(n):=\ $ "If $A\subseteq \Bbb N$ and $\exists a\in A\colon a\le n$, then $A$ has a minimal element"

by induction on $n$.